# Close copied worksheet when exporting into CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, office-2010

I try to save each worksheet of an excel spreadsheet into CSV files. The following script do the job. The line `.Parent.Close savechanges:=False` is supposed to close the created worksheet but when uncommented the script stops after the first sheet. If I comment the line, all the sheets are processed.

```
Dim newWks As Worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
wks.Copy 'to a new workbook
Set newWks = ActiveSheet
With newWks
.SaveAs Filename:="C:\home\tmp\base\" & wks.Name & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
.Parent.Close savechanges:=False
End With
Next wks

MsgBox "done with: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the activeworkbook. If you want to close the newly created object then do something like this (tested it and it works for me):

```
Dim newWkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  wks.Copy 'to a new workbook
  Set newWkb = ActiveWorkbook
  With newWkb
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\home\tmp\base\" & wks.Name & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
    newWkb.Close savechanges:=False
  End With
Next wks

MsgBox "done with: " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: I think that your code and Sydney's do the same thing, although yours more directly identifies the workbook to be closed.  In other words "Set newWkb = ActiveWorkbook"  is the same as "Set newWks = ActiveSheet.Parent," which is effectively what Sydney's code does.  Both yours and Sydney's code work fine for me in Excel 2010.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the only difference is the SaveAs is performed on the worksheet in the original and mine is SaveAs on the new workbook. So, I don't know why it wasn't working for him, it works now though! Odd.

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize until reading this post that you can do a Worksheet.SaveAs.  I learn something new all the time on SO.